# Can my tablet connect to a 4g pocket wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

I bought my tablet in lazada and i am planning on buying a pocket wifi, so i want to know if my tablet can connect to a 4g pocket wifi. after reading articles about data connection hotspot something like that, it made me more confused. please help and explain and elaborate. Im gonna buy it at lazada.

MY tablet - Cherry Mobile Superion Probe Android 4.2 Jelly Bean (White)

POCKET WIFI CHOICES:
1.) 3G - Huawei E5330 21Mbps 3G Mobile WiFi Hotspot
2.) 4G - Huawei E5373 4G Mobile Wifi

Answer (score 1):

Before buying pocket WiFi, switch on the 4g hotspot in your mobile and try to connect to it through tablet. If it works then proceed to buy what you are planning.

Note: while connecting be sure the SSID, security type and password are correct or not.